# How to put a string into a position in a byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

I've pretty much reached a brick wall and could use some advice on how to proceed with a project for one of my courses. Here's code I'm trying to get to work:

```
for(i = 0; i < sendData.length; i++){
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(C[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Encrypted Message: ");
    for(i = 0; i < sendData.length; i++){
        System.out.print(sendData[i]);
    }
```

As a bit of a background this is for code for RC4 encryption. I've trying to put the value of hex in a position in sendData[] which is a fixed byte array. Because hex is a string I haven't really found a way to put that value in a position in the sendData array. I know I can't use the getBytes() function as it completely gets rid of the hex values. If anyone has any idea on how to take a string value and put it into a position in a fixed byte array it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand Integer is of `4 bytes` not a single byte so you will need array `4 bytes` rather than storing in loop with single bytes. You can convert an Integer to byte[] like below.

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(int value)    
{  
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);  
    return bb.putInt(value).array();  
}  

public long toInteger(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    return buffer.getInt();
}
```